# How do you do sumif with equation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I want to do a `SUMIF`, but I need to enter an equation for `sum_range` parameter, so normally, to do a `SUMIF`, you write:

```
=SUMIF(CRITERIA_RANGE,CRITERIA,SUM_RANGE)
```

This is great, but what if I need to do some calculation in my summation?  So for example:

```
=SUMIF(CRITERIA_RANGE,CRITERIA,COL1*COL2)
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` is commonly used in this case

Eg

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((CRITERIA_RANGE=CRITERIA)*COL1*COL2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A different answer (NOT FOR POINTS).

**Explanation**

The reason why you cannot use `SUMIF` in your scenario is because `SUMIF` cannot handle `Arrays` as sumproduct does and hence I would go with Chris's suggestion of using `SUMPRODUCT`

**Alternative**

Here is one more way to achieve what you want.

`=SUM(IF(CRITERIA_RANGE=CRITERIA,COL1*COL2,""))`

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Please note that this is an `ARRAY FORMULA` which means that instead of pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: This is indeed a viable alternative, although I would always opt for the SUMPRODUCT() solution as well, especially since a lot of Excel users cannot wrap their heads around the `Array` functionality.